# How to install Canon PIXMA MP510 printer

Tags: printing, canon

How to install a Canon PIXMA MP510 printer? I have tried to install but the system said that "mp510series" is not in the file of michael-gruz filenames.

Comment: Have you checked the Canon website for Linux drivers?

Comment: so this is an 11yr old printer; still going well? and seems to me that gutenprint supports it: if you just plug your 510 in via usb, does ubuntu not recognise it and configure it? If you right-click on the icon; if it is set up; and look 4 down in properties; there is a line called MAKE & MODEL and it should say gutenprint 510 ... if not, try the CHANGE button to the right; click on the CANON book; scroll down through a vast list of printers till you should see MP510 as an option; the michael-gruz support all seems to have gone away about 4 yrs ago I had read